# ошибка созданя дополнения VSTO уровня документа

Tags: c#, vsto

добрый день
пытаюсь создать "Книгу VSTO для Excel 2013 и Excel 2016" через мастер в VisualStudio 2012, результат: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не удалось включить программный доступ к системе проектов Microsoft Office Visual Basic для приложений. Если запущено приложение MIcrosoft Office  Word или Microsoft Office Excel, это может быть причиной запрета на включение программного доступа. Выйдите из приложения Word или Excel перед тем, как открыть или создать проект.

Конечно же все офисные приложения закрыты (тестировалось сразу после перезагрузки)

Что делать?

Comment: смотрите какие-нибудь фоновые процессы

Comment: в настройках Excel по условию закрыт доступ к VBA, нужно было в Параметрах макросов включить  "Доверять доступ к объектной модели проектов VBA", Но час от часу не легче, теперь при попытке создать проект выдаёт ошибку: "Не удаётся открыть проект. Книга Excel ExcelWorkbook1.xlsx отсутствует или повреждена" даже при создании новой пустой книги не используя за основу какую-либо другую книгу или шаблон.

Comment: Причем тут это?

Comment: Если вы самостоятельно нашли ответ на свой вопрос, можете опубликовать его

Answer (score 1):

в настройках Excel\Word по умолчанию закрыт доступ к VBA, нужно  в соответствующем приложении в **Параметрах макросов** включить "Доверять доступ к объектной модели проектов VBA"